# Separating Enantiomers

Tags: organic-chemistry, chirality

I understand that you can react enantiomers with a chiral molecule to resolve the enantiomers of interest into diastereomers.

However I do not understand how exactly the added chiral molecule can make the enantiomers of interest into diastereomers.

Can someone please explain the process/mechanism ?

For example: here is a picture from my textbook. 
[image]
How are those two salts Diastereomers, even though they are mirror images of each other.

Comment: The ways are probably numerous. One mechanism that I remember has the chiral counterpart on a column. So you would basically do like an ion exchange. You'd then flush the column to release the other enantiomer. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_resolution

Comment: Are you sure they are mirror images? Look at the salt as a whole, not the individual ions.

Comment: The example on UC Davis ChemWiki is better, as they also offer the actual physical data with the compounds: http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Organic_Chemistry/Fundamentals/Isomerism_in_Organic_Compounds/Diastereomers_and_Optical_Resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enantiomers are mirror reflections, they have **same** physical and chemical properties. This like left and right hand.

Diastereomers have **different** physical and chemical properties. You can separate them on chromatography column or by crystallization.

In your example upper and bottom products are *not* mirror reflections.
Mirror relection of upper product looks like:

[image]
[image]

Just play with the 3D models in any drawing software to get the point.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. So the anion salt has to be taken into account as well. I was under the impression that you would only have to look a the cation.